# Given vectors spaces $V,W$ with finite dimension,is that true to claim that if $W \subseteq V$ and $\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim}(W)$ implies that $W=V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given vectors spaces $V,W$ with finite dimension,is that true to claim that if $W \subseteq V$ and $\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim}(W)$ implies that $W=V$?

For finite sets $A$ and $B$ with $\left|A\right|=\left|B\right|$ I know that if $A \subseteq B$  then $A=B$,but I'm not sure if the same does hold for vector spaces with finite dimension.

If it does hold then please give me a proof,if it's not true please provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Pick a basis of $W$. That's an independent family of vectors in $V$ and hence can be extended to a basis of $V$, but without adding any vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If we note $k=\dim W$, we can write $W= \text{Vect} (e_1,...,e_k)$ where $(e_1,...e_k)$ is a basis of $W$.

Then $\text{Vect} (e_1,...,e_k) \subset V$, so $(e_1,...e_k)$ is a family of $k$ elements of $V$ that is linearly-independent, and as $\dim V = k$, it's a basis of $V$.

So $W=V=\text{Vect} (e_1,...,e_k)$.